# Silverlight 4 - BusyIndicator working with a DomainDataSource

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, busyindicator

Can someone please help me get this to work?  I am trying not to use code behind as I'm putting a little test application together to test WCF Ria Services.

```
<my2:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding ElementName=targetDomainDataSource}" BusyContent="{Binding}" DisplayAfter="0:0:0.1">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your binding too `IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, ElementName=targetDomainDataSource}"`

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks, I guess I didn't think that the IsBusy was possible as it doesn't appear in the intellisense.  Thanks again.